# Formulating a mixed integer programming problem with a binary maximization term

Tags: optimization, combinatorics, operations-research, linear-programming

**Real-world description of the problem:**

In the US, funding for school lunch programs is given to local school districts by the Federal government.  If >=40% of students in a school ***or group of schools*** is low income then all students in the school get free lunch automatically. A district has many schools (50 in a mid-sized district up to 1800 in the largest, NYC) and can group them in any way and form any number of groups to maximize the number of students provided lunch. For each group, the low income percentage is calculated by dividing all low income students in a group by the total number of students in the group (it is a weighted average not a simple average of the low income percentage.)

**Example:**

- School A: total students = 1000, low income students = 500, percent = 50%
- School B: total students = 500, low income students = 100, percent = 20%
- School C: total students = 800, low income students = 312, percent = 39%

**No grouping: {A}, {B}, {C}**

- Free lunch schools: A
- Number of free lunch students: 1000
- Number of low income students with free lunch: 500

**Grouping all: {A, B, C}**

- Low income percent= 39.6
- Free lunch schools: 0
- Number of free lunch students: 0
- Number of low income students with free lunch: 0

**Group: {A, B}, {C}**

- Low income percent= 40.0%, 39%
- Free lunch schools: 2
- Number of free lunch students: 1500
- Number of low income students with free lunch: 600

**Group: {A, C}, {B}**

- Low income percent= 45%, 20%
- Free lunch schools: 2
- Number of free lunch students: 1800
- Number of low income students with free lunch: 812

**Group: {B, C}, {A}**

- Low income percent= 31%, 50%
- Free lunch schools: 1
- Number of free lunch students: 1000
- Number of low income students with free lunch: 500

---

**Abstract description of the problem**

There are n elements s where:
$$
\{ S \in  \mathbb{Z} | s  >0, ( s_{1} \ldots s_{n} ) \}
$$

Each element, s has two values t and l:
$$
\{ t \in  \mathbb{Z} | t  > 0 \}
$$
$$
\{ l \in  \mathbb{Z} | l  > 0, l \leq t \}
$$

Each element must be placed into exactly 1 group.

A group can have between 0 and all elements.

$$
\{ G \in  \mathbb{Z} | g  >0, g \leq S_{n}, ( g_{1} \ldots g_{n} ) \}
$$

Scoring: if the sum(l)/sum(t) in a group >= 0.4 then the score for that group is sum(t), else it is 0

$$
    g(l,t) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        \sum t, & \text{for } \frac{\sum l}{\sum t} \geq 0.4\\
        0, & \text{for } \frac{\sum l}{\sum t} < 0.4
        \end{array}\right\}
$$

Objective:
Maximize the sum of the group scores

$$
\begin{array}{lr}
\text{maximize} & \sum_{i=1}^{g_{n}} g(l,t)
\end{array}
$$

---

**Question**

This seems to be a mixed integer linear program problem. However, the maximization function is more complicated than I have seen in most examples. How would I formulate this for a solver like OR-tools for python?

Comment: You might be overcomplicating this.  Letting $n$ be the vector of school sizes and $b$ the vector of low income student counts in schools, you need to find a binary vector $x$ that maximizes $n\cdot x$ subject to the constraint that $a\cdot x \le 0$ where $a = n - 0.4b.$  That's about as simple a program as one can conceive of.

Comment: I'm working on implementing the suggestion in or-tools. To clarify, did you mean: $$ a =0.4n -b $$  Is the binary vector x only applicable to assigning schools to two groups? My application called for assigning them to between 1 and n groups where n was the number of schools.

Comment: Why would you need more than two groups?  If two qualify, then you can combine them into a single qualifying group.

Comment: In the simplified example with three schools two groups is sufficient, but a real application may have 50 schools all the way to 1800 schools to be assigned to groups. Adding additional groups provides more ways to allocate schools in a way where most groups groups are just above the qualifying threshold.

Comment: But that flexibility does not create better solutions.  You seem to be working with additional objectives or constraints that you haven't stated.

Comment: You might want to move this to (the new) Operations Research  Stack Exchange https://or.stackexchange.com/